# How do I align a button with the bottom of an EditText in an Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

With my layout, I would like the `EditText`s to fill all of the horizontal space on their row, but leave the remaining space for a button to its right.

I would also like the buttons to be aligned to the bottom of the `EditText` that is on its row.

Currently, the buttons are not aligned to the bottom of their `EditText`, and I would like to know how I can achieve this.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

And here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp" > 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">          

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:ems="8"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:hint="enter name" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/micNameButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameLayout">       

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/notesEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="8"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:hint="enter notes" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/micNotesButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping your margin attributes in the LinearLayout, and not in the actual EditText or ImageButton. And set the gravity of the layout to `bottom`.

(Edit: Also notice that I added `android:orientation="horizontal"` to the LinearLayouts. You should always have an orientation when child views use layout_weight)

It should look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp" > 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="8"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:hint="enter name" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/micNameButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameLayout">       

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/notesEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="8"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:hint="enter notes" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/micNotesButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Okay I got it, I'll make sure to always use the orientation attribute with layout_weight.  Thanks again!